# How to add the Cover Letter with Friggeri resume?

Tags: friggeri-cv

I want to add coverletter before Resume.

```
\documentclass[]{myfriggeri-cv} % Add 'print' as an option into the square bracket to remove colors from this template for printing
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{skype}{HTML}{12A5F4}
\definecolor{html5}{HTML}{e34c26}
\definecolor{php}{HTML}{6c7eb7}
\definecolor{db}{HTML}{FF9900}
\definecolor{linkedin}{HTML}{1683BB}
%\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % Specify the bibliography file to include publications

\begin{document}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}
\header{First Name}{Last Name}{Name of Profession} % Your name and current job title/field

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{aside} % In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\section{personal info}
\emph{D.O.B}
\emph{Nationality} Pakistani
\emph{Marital status}
\section{{\FA \faHome}}
~
\section{\faPhone}
%+0 (000) 111 1112
~
\section{\faEnvelope}
{abcd@outlook.com}
%\href{http://www.smith.com}{http://www.smith.com}
%\href{http://facebook.com/johnsmith}{fb://jsmith}
\section{languages}
\emph{proficient} English
\emph{mother tongue}  Urdu
\section{computer literacy}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} MS-Office
\end{aside}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Objective SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{objective}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{experience}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2013 - Now}
{Name od Employer}
{City, Country}
{\emph{Job Responsibility} \\
\begin{itemize}
\item
\item
\item
\end{itemize}}
\end{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{education}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2011}
{Masters {\normalfont in Business Administration}}
{Name of University, City}
{Specialization in Supply Chain Management}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2008}
{Bachelors {\normalfont in Business Administration}}
{Name of University, City}
{Specialization in Management}

%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AWARDS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{additional skills}
\section{references}
 %

 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 %  COMMUNICATION SKILLS SECTION
 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 \section{communication skills}

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  INTERESTS SECTION
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%
\section{interests}   
%
%\textbf{professional:} data analysis, company profiling, risk analysis, economics, web design, web app creation, software design, marketing \textbf{personal:} piano, chess, cooking, dancing, running
%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  PUBLICATIONS SECTION
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: I applaud your ambition, but perhaps you could share a little more detail -- using actual but [minimal](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528)  LaTeX code -- about what is preventing you from doing it.

Comment: Are there any news? The question as it stands is unclear.